# What could be the more accurate time complexity for this algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

This is my program:

```
 for(m!=n){
   if(m>n)
     m=m-n;
   else 
     n=n-m; 
 }
```

If I take m=16 and n=2, then the loop is executing 7 times.
if I take m=16 and n=12 then the loop is executing 3 times.
How to give a more accurate time complexity for this program and what is the procedure for calculating the time complexity for this type of algorithm in which we have two inputs?

Comment: Time complexity seems to be infinite for `m=1` and `n=0`, so if you don't specify some more constraints, then it's hard to answer. Big-O typically only makes sense for algorithms that can be proven to terminate.

Comment: don't take invalid input like i want to calculate time complexity for very large inputs(like we usually do) say n and m

Comment: If there are any cases where some code does not terminate, its complexity is indeterminate.   Saying "ignore invalid inputs" doesn't change that.   The loop will also have undefined behaviour if `m` and `n` are of signed integral type, and have opposite sign (e.g. one is positive and the other is negative)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking an answer, and the answer is indeterminate.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `m,n > 0`, the time complexity is `O(max(n,m))` (or, equivalently, `O(n+m)`).

The reasoning is:

- On every iteration, either `n` decreases, or `m` decreases, so there cannot be more than `n + m` iterations (upper bound).
- We can present a worst case scenario `n=1`, `m=k` (and, symmetrically, `n=k`, `m=1`), which gives us exactly `k` iterations (lower bound).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your m and n follow certain constraint and loop doesn't go into infinite loop.ie `m>0` and `n>0` or `m!=1` and `n=0`

`If m>=n`

`if m%n==0` then loop will execute m/n-1 times 
 `else if m%n!=0` then loop will execute ceil(m/n) times.

```
If m<n
```

`if n%m==0` then loop will execute m/n-1 times 
 `else if n%m!=0` then loop will execute ceil(m/n) times.

in either case complexity will be `0(m/n)` or `0(n/m)`which is equal to `0(m)` or `0(n)` respectively.

Comment: `o(m/n)` can be equal to `o(n)`?

Comment: @deniss is this sloution correct?
This looking weird because we cannot say O(1/n) is equal to O(n) not have different meanings

Comment: @newby, `O(n/m)` is _in_ `O(n)` (for `n,m >= 1`) in the same sense as `O(n)` is in `O(n^2)`, but I'd argue this algorithm is not `O(n/m)`. Counterexample is `n=k, m=k+1`, which is reduced to `n=k, m=1` after the first iteration and loops for `k+1` iterations total.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear answer for the time complexity. The number of iterations depends on m and n.

1. if m == n the loop exits in 1 step.
2. if m == 1 and n == 100, loop will take 100 steps.

So, if you keep n constant and keep increasing m, you will get a cyclic pattern.

The image below shows the no of iterations for n = 2000 and m ranging from 1 to 10000

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have no prove that the loop shall end.

In particular if any of m or n is zero, it will cycle forever.

So time complexity is not definite.

Add constraints.

Hope this help.